# My window content disappears after a few seconds

Tags: directx, directx-11, sharpdx

I programmed with DirectX 9 / OpenGL and C++ some years ago and I wanted to start a new hobby project with SharpDX and DirectX 11. I made the first basic steps and everything looks nice, but I only the opened my application and saw, that everything's as expected and closed them afterwards.

Today, my application was opened for about 20 seconds and suddenly my whole window content disappeared. I checked the official SharpDX samples and I had the same problem with the official *MiniTri* sample from SharpDX. Finally, I tested the offical samples from Microsoft in *Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)*'s Direct3D11 Tutorial 02, which does nothing more than showing a colored triangle. Even the official sample from Microsoft (which does neither use SharpDX nor C#) has the same issue on my computer. Of course, I used my favored search engine for quite some time, but I was not able to find anyone with the same issue. Maybe I searched for the wrong keywords.

After around 14-20 seconds, the content (i.e. vertices) of the window disappear. I have no rotation, animation, movement or anything, just simple triangles with a simple color.

I'd be very happy, if you can help me!

Comment: On Which OS are you running? What kind of GPU do you have? Is the graphics driver up-to-date?

Comment: Hello xoofx, I am using Microsoft's Windows 10, 64-bit with a Radeon HD 6500 from Sapphire (OEM). I am not absolutely sure, if it's exactly this GPU, since I am at work, but I think it is.

I have the latest Windows Updates and the latest version of the ATI GPU driver.

I don't have any problemy when playing games like "Space Engineers" or any other game done with DirectX 11. So I am pretty confused, what's the source of my problem. :-(

Comment: @xoofx, I checked my Windows Device Manager. I have a AMD Radeon HD 6900 GPU. I am using the latest AMD Catalyst driver 15.11.1 from last month. I analyzed several other samples from the official SharpDX sample s and I encounter the same issue. I have no idea what I can do :'-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent several hours to figure out, why some simple official SharpDX and DirectX tutorials do not work correctly on my machine. Finally, I decided to ignore that issue and contine with the development of my game. It was a great decision since it turned out, that I don't have any issue with the advanced tutorials! The MultiCube sample from SharpDX worked very well and its content did not disappear. So, I figured out that my problem does not occur, if my graphics card is kept busy. I continued my development while running Fallout 4 minimized in the background. Developing this way, my content did not disappear.

I started to implement a user interface for my game using Direct2D1 (with SharpDX). It turned out that using Direct2D1 solves my issue and the content stopped to disappear.

I am not absolutely sure what caused my issue, but apparently my GPU got bored and stopped rendering my simple primitives. :-D Using Direct2D1 for UI solves this problem anyhow.